# How to remove useless libraries from Java Netbeans

Tags: java, libraries

I am making a Java Swing project and it includes like 80-90 libraries. I am not using most of them but I added them as they came in a pack. e.g. I have added all lib files from javamail, though I know that I am only using  SMTP. Is there any way to find out which libraries I am not using???. Is there a safe way to remove these libraries without causing a conflict?
I am using Netbeans IDE. Please help.

Comment: Reflection, dynamic classloading and other tricks make it possible that you'll discover at runtime that you're lacking dependencies that do not get referenced directly.

A common example is JDBC. The drivers are instantiated through a JDBC URL which then is checked against the loaded drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means management of library dependencies. There is the **ant/ivy combo**, but I use the **maven** build infrastructure.

Create a new maven project in NetBeans, add all sources (to src/main/java), and then start adding **dependencies** (appears in the project explorer).

Transitive dependencies are dealt with.

This is ideal, as also library versions are maintained.

Mind: maven first loads the libraries with their metadata in a local "repository", per default .m2 in the user directory.

I can only recommend maven.

Comment: The method works well, but I was able to do the trial and error method. There were only like 80 libraries. Anyways thank you I will use the advice for future use.